# Closure Compiler externs for the Foundation CSS framework

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I want to run the Closure Compiler on a JavaScript file that initiates plugins for the Foundation CSS framework. The [Foundation initialization](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html) is simple:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

However, when I run the Closure Compiler with advanced optimizations, this gets compiled to `$(document).f();`.

How do I write an extern to tell the Closure Compiler to ignore `$(document).foundation();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by copying and modifying the `$(document).ready()` extern from the [jQuery 1.9 externs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js).

The original:

```
/**
 * @param {function()} handler
 * @return {!jQuery}
 */
jQuery.prototype.ready = function(handler) {};
```

And the modified version:

```
/**
 * @param {function()} handler
 * @return {!jQuery}
 */
jQuery.prototype.foundation = function(handler) {};
```

Comment: No need to rewrite `.ready` in the externs file. Just add foundation, and other needed jQuery-based functions added by plugins, to the prototype.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that poorly. I meant that I copied `.ready` and modified the copy to add `.foundation`.